# Closing 'option' tags with HTML Agility Pack while preserving innertext

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want HTML-Agility-Pack to close any open 'option' tags while still preserving the innertext. My goal is to capture the following:

- Option Value (i.e. Value = 1)
- Option Innertext (i.e. Value = Alberta)

The C# code I wrote is dependent on the option closing tags to appear after the innertext.

Here's the original HTML:

```
<select id="Province" >
<option value=""> -- Select province --</option>
    <option value="1">Alberta
    <option value="2">British Columbia
    <option value="3">Manitoba
    <option value="4">New Brunswick
    <option value="5">Newfoundland
    <option value="6">Northwest Territories
    <option value="7">Nova Scotia
    <option value="8">Nunavut
    <option value="9">Ontario
    <option value="10">Prince Edward Island
    <option value="11">Quebec
    <option value="12">Saskatchewan
    <option value="13">Yukon
</select>
```

Resulting HTML formatted by HTML-AgilityPack:

```
<select id="Province" >
<option value=""> -- Select province --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>Alberta
    <option value="2"></option>British Columbia
    <option value="3"></option>Manitoba
    <option value="4"></option>New Brunswick
    <option value="5"></option>Newfoundland
    <option value="6"></option>Northwest Territories
    <option value="7"></option>Nova Scotia
    <option value="8"></option>Nunavut
    <option value="9"></option>Ontario
    <option value="10"></option>Prince Edward Island
    <option value="11"></option>Quebec
    <option value="12"></option>Saskatchewan
    <option value="13"></option>Yukon
</select>
```

As you can see, the  doesn't take into account to include the innertext. Is it possible to have the closing tag added after the innertext?

For example:

```
<option value="1">Alberta</option>
```

Here's the C# code that's being used to parse the HTML:

```
static void LoadProvinces()
    {
        //Read the HTML File and save it to the string 'rawProvinces'
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("ProvincesCheckout.htm");
        string rawProvinces = myFile.ReadToEnd();

        //This tells HTML-Agility-Pack to close all open Option Tags
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["option"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

        //Load the rawProvinces string into HTML-Agility-Pack
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(rawProvinces);

        //Convert the parsed HTML to the string variable 'parsedHtml' and save it to 'hap.htm'
        string parsedHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("hap.htm");
        file.WriteLine(parsedHtml);
        file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't work, but it should. Although you can also do this yourself using the String class and its methods:

```
            // Get all option elements
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            // Get the outer position of the NextSibling (which would be the text we want to surround with </option>)
            int nextPosition = rawProvinces.IndexOf(node.NextSibling.OuterHtml) + node.NextSibling.OuterHtml.Trim().Length;
            // Check if there isn't already a </option> element
            if (!rawProvinces.Substring(nextPosition, 8).StartsWith("</option"))
            {
                // Add the element
                rawProvinces = rawProvinces.Insert(nextPosition, "</option>");
            }
        }
```